# Fetching text with xpath in dynamic html structure

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I have a lot of html and want to process it via xpath. There are two possible ways text can occur:

```
<div>
  The Text
</div>
<!-- OR -->
<div>
  <span>The Text</span>
</div>
<!-- BUT NOT -->
<div> other text
  <span>The Text</span>
</div> other text
```

Is there a way I can fetch "The Text" with a single xpath expression?

**edit:**

concrete structure:

```
<div id="content">
<h1>...</h1>
<div>
    ...
</div>
<div>
    <span>The Text</span>
</div>
```

I'm getting the *content* node via `//div[@id='content'][1]` and reuse it for other purposes. On this context-node, I tried to execute `./div[2]/span/text() | ./div[not(span)][2]/text()`. It works if there is no span, but returns blank/null if there is a spawn. Im using the Java xpath implementation. The div is always the second one of the content-node.

Comment: Just get the div and read its textContent property

Comment: It would be helpful to show what XPath you tried, what the result was, and how it differs from the result you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div/span/text() | div[not(span)]/text()
```

should do the trick. This selects text nodes that are children of the `<span>` (if there is a `<span>`), as well as text nodes that are children of the `<div>` if there is no `<span>`.

You'll have to modify the `div` parts to reflect the context from which you're evaluating the XPath expression. If you want to do this with all `<div>` elements in the document, then change `div` to `//div`.

## Update:

Based on the new context information you posted, the above XPath should be modified to:

```
./div[2]/span/text() | ./div[2][not(span)]/text()
```

However I don't see why your version is returning no text when there is a `<span>` element. Can you give more context -- your java code that's evaluating the XPath; maybe a more detailed snippet of your input HTML? Is the sample input HTML really exactly representative of your actual input? Could there be another `</div>` in there that's going unnoticed?

Comment: I added a better and more concrete example, LarsH

Comment: It's finally is working now, thank you. I'm not sure where the problem was, I could swear I tried that already...

Comment: @cara: It probably started working in order to save face, once more people started looking at it. :-)